# Find the type of goods that takes up the most space in the warehouse

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sum, max

I have query like this

```
select StockId, ProductType, sum(ProductVolume) as ProductTypeVolume
from myTable
where InStock = 1
group by StockId, ProductType
```

with result like this

| StockId | ProductType | ProductTypeVolume |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | Type1 | 65 |
| 10 | Type2 | 25 |
| 10 | Type3 | 45 |
| 20 | Type2 | 80 |
| 20 | Type4 | 60 |
| 20 | Type5 | 20 |

I need to get a result where there will be two rows, one for each StockId, with the largest ProductTypeVolume like this

| StockId | ProductType | ProductTypeVolume |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | Type1 | 65 |
| 20 | Type2 | 80 |

Comment: use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StockId ORDER BY ProductTypeVolume DESC)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `CTE`, `subquery` and `group by`:

```
WITH t
     AS (SELECT stockid,
                producttype,
                Sum(productvolume) AS ProductTypeVolume
         FROM   mytable
         WHERE  instock = 1
         GROUP  BY stockid,
                   producttype)


SELECT A.stockid,
       B.producttype,
       A.producttypevolume
FROM   (SELECT stockid,
               Max(producttypevolume) ProductTypeVolume
        FROM   t
        GROUP  BY stockid) A
       JOIN t B
         ON A.stockid = B.stockid
            AND A.producttypevolume = B.producttypevolume
```

You can use `row_number` as follows

```
SELECT TOP(2) stockid,
              producttype,
              producttypevolume
--,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StockId ORDER BY ProductTypeVolume DESC)
FROM   t
ORDER  BY Row_number()
            OVER (
              partition BY stockid
              ORDER BY producttypevolume DESC) ASC
```

Comment: then use with, I have assign it

Comment: This looks good

Comment: you can use row_number thanks to Squirrel